# express-session error "refused to execute script from because its mime type..." without express.static('public')

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

I am new to express and was building a basic test of the passport js local strategy. I was receiving the following message in the console of home.html after successful authentication: "Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3200/homescript.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled." After checking the syntax of the  on home.html was correct, I eventually resolved the issue simply by adding app.use(express.static('public') to app.js. I suspect this is related to relative paths in express-session, but I'd like to understand exactly what the issue was to avoid in the future!

```
passport //Root
|_ public
   |_ home.html //served after user is authenticated
   |_ homescript.js //only loads if app.use(express.static('public') is in app.js
   |_ index.html //presents link to login page
   |_ index.js
   |_ login.html
|_ app.js
|_ helpers.js
```

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');
const morgan = require('morgan');
require('dotenv').config();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const store = new session.MemoryStore();
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const { findById, findByUsername } = require('./helpers');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3200
const public = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

app
    .use(morgan('dev'))
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    .use(session({
        secret: process.env.COOKIESTRING,
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10,
            sameSite: 'strict'
        },
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store
    }))
    .use(passport.initialize())
    .use(passport.session())
    //.use(express.static('public')); Uncommenting this will fully resolve the mime error. Why?

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    findById(id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        done(null, user);
    })
})

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        findByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);}
            if (!user) {
                return done(null,false);}
            if (user.password != password) {
                return done(null,false);}
            return done(null, user);
        })
    }
))

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect('/home');
})

app.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
    req.logout(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.redirect('/');
    });
})

app.get('/api/data', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user.dataAccess) {
        responseObj = {
            data: 'protected data',
            user: req.user.username,
        }
        res.json(responseObj);
    } else {
        res.json({message: 'User does not have access to this data'})
    }
})

app.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(public, 'login.html'));
})

app.get('/home', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(public, 'home.html'));
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```